# ios/cocos2d how to make menuitem to disappear after being activated?

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, menu, cocos2d-iphone

i"m new here :)
my first question :
i"m trying to make simple interaction ,- after menuitem is being pressed , i"m starting spritesheet animation of it.
look"s like i can"t straightly animate menuitem with spritesheet (but i think it wou"d be right)
also i can`t do -

```
menuItem.visible =false:
```

in function , that is activated by that button
also i can`t reOrder menuitem to   z:-10

here is my code:
.h :

```
CCSprite *p1S2;
CCAction *p1A2;
```

.m :

```
@interface FirstPage ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *p1A2;
@property (nonatomic, retain)  CCSprite *p1S2;

@end

@implementation FirstPage
@synthesize p1S2 = _p1S2;
@synthesize p1A2 = _p1A2;

- (id)init
{
    if ((self = [super init]))
    {

        CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
        bg1 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"st_01_bg1.png"];
        bg1.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, 512);
        [self addChild:bg1];
        bg2 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"st_01_bg2.png"];
        bg2.position = ccp(screenSize.width/2, 128);
        [self addChild:bg2 ];

 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
         @"button.plist"];
        CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet2 = [CCSpriteBatchNode 
                                               batchNodeWithFile:@"button.png"];
            [self addChild:spriteSheet2 z:6];
            NSMutableArray *AnimFrames2 = [NSMutableArray array];

            for(int i = 1; i <= 30; ++i) {
                [AnimFrames2 addObject:
                 [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
                  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%d.png", i]]];

            }
    CCAnimation *becomeAnim2 = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:AnimFrames2 delay:0.04f];

            self.p1S2 = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"rostok1.png"];        
           _p1S2.position = ccp(638,530);

            self.p1A2=[CCSequence actions:[CCRepeat actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:becomeAnim2 restoreOriginalFrame:NO]times:200],nil];
            [spriteSheet2 addChild:_p1S2 z:6];
            [_p1S2 runAction:_p1A2];
            _p1S2.visible=false;

    CCMenuItem *menuItem1 = [CCMenuItemImage itemFromNormalImage:@"knopka_01_lisik.png" 
                                                           selectedImage:@"knopka_02_lisik.png" target:self selector:@selector(button1Tapped:)];

            CCMenu *Menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:menuItem1, nil];
            Menu.position = ccp(638,530);        
            [Menu alignItemsHorizontally];
            [self addChild:Menu z:7];
        }
    return self;
}
- (void)button1Tapped:(id)sender {
 _p1S2.visible = true;
           }

} 
@end
```

any advices on how to do it right ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is using an image for your menu item. You can use different things instead of that image, such as labels, or **sprites**. Give this a try:

```
        CCMenuItemSprite *sprite1 = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:@"Your Sprite.png" selectedSprite:@"YourSelectedSrite.png" target:self selector:@selector(animation)];
```

You have your default sprite, then when it is selected your selected sprite, then the target (usually self), and then the selector. It is in that selector that you need to put in your animation code, and whatever code you want.